# Softlayer Windows - post provisioning script is not being downloaded after the VM is provisioned on SL portal

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Softlayer Windows - The post provisioning script is not being downloaded after the VM is provisioned on the portal.

Answer (score 0):

well we need more information about this such as:

1. What version of windows are you using?
2. Does this issue happens using the control portal, the API, or both"?
3. Are you sure that your machine is able to reach the script?

Anyway this is probably an issue with Softlayer and the best way to addres this is by submitting a ticket with a subject related to provisioning or virtual servers (NOT API because this is an issue related to the provisioning not the API use).

Regards